# Remove specific properties from Array objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

For example I have this array, if I stringfy it it would be like this:

```
[{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}]
```

How can I do for remove from the 2 cars: the doors and price. And only leave in the array "car" and "id"? For example:

```
[{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2"}]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please look at the tags before using them... It clearly says `Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You want to modify the same array or are you ok with creating a new one?

Comment: can you show us what you have done or what research have you done?

Comment: *I have this array* where is the array in your question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to customise your result array, taking a callback function as parameter which returns a new customised object, having only `car` and `ID` properties, in each iteration.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

This is how should be your code:

```
var results = arr.map(function(item){
  return {car : item["car"], ID : item["ID"]}
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}];

var results = arr.map(function(item){
  return {car : item["car"], ID : item["ID"]}
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
let arr = [{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}]

let arr1 = arr.map(({car, ID}) => ({car, ID}));
let arr2 = arr.map(({Doors, price, ...remainingAttrs}) => remainingAttrs);

console.log('arr1:', arr1);
console.log('arr2:', arr2);
```

With **ES6 syntax**, you can deconstruct each object to create new one without writing a loop.

In your case, total number of fields remaining is same as the total number of deleted
Following are the two approaches:

- If less number of fields are to be **preserved**, then you can go with:

> const arr1 = arr.map(({car, ID}) => ({car, ID}))

- If less number of fields are to be **removed**, then you can go with:

> const arr2 = arr.map(({Doors, price, ...remainingAttrs}) =>
> remainingAttrs)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to all other answers

Cleaner approach using ES6 syntax

```js
var originalArray =[{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}];

var immutableArray = originalArray.map(({Doors, price, ...rest})=> rest);

console.log(immutableArray);
```

Comment: It gives es linting error that 'Doors ' and 'price' is defined but never used.

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate over your array deleting the property on each object.

Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  delete myArray[i].myProperty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answers, with ES6 and to avoid mutation and some ESlint issues.

```js
const Array = [{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"}, 
              {"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}];
const newArray = Array.map((object) => {
             const {car, ID} = object;
             return {car, ID};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check comment for explanation:

```js
var array=[{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}];

var resultArr = array.map(function(obj){
  //we take only key-value pairs we need using JS bracket notation
  return {"car":obj["car"],"ID":obj["ID"]};
});

console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking for the `delete` operator to fully remove those properties. It could look something like this:

```
var array = [{"car":"Toyota","ID":"1", "Doors": "4", "price": "20.000"},{"car":"Chevrolet","ID":"2", "Doors": "2", "price": "15.000"}]

for (car of array) {
    delete(car.Doors);
    delete(car.price);
}
```

You could also look into using Array.splice() for faster performance on large arrays.